# Handle Directory Exists Exception

Tags: powershell, exception

I am new to PowerShell. I have a piece of code which checks whether a folder "ilalog" exists or not. When I run this script first time, it is checking for the folder "ilalog",if it does not exist,it is creating. When I run the script second time. I receive the error below:

> An item with the specified name D:\Temp\ilalog already exists
>   "FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   DirectoryExist,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand".

how to handle this exception

I have tried using try and Catch block

```
 $rgflder="ilalog"
    [bool]$checkrg=Test-Path D:\Gdump\$rgfolder -PathType Any
    if ( $checkrg -eq $False)
    {
try{
    New-Item -Path "D:\Gdump" -Name "$rgflder" -ItemType "directory"
    }
catch [System.IO.IOException] 
    {
            if ($_.CategoryInfo.Category -eq $resExistErr) {Write-host "Dir Exist"}
} 
}       
else
{
Write-Output "Directory Exists" 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue processing your script while taking action based on an error type, a simple way is to just examine the `$error` variable. Using Trap may be an option as well.

```
$error.clear()
New-Item -Path "D:\Gdump" -Name "$rgflder" -ItemType "directory"
if ($error[0].Exception.GetType().Fullname -eq 'System.IO.IOException') {
    "Dir Exists"
}
else {
    "Dir was created"
}
```

If you want to use try-catch, you need to treat your non-terminating error as a terminating error to activate the catch block. You can do this with `-ErrorAction Stop`.

```
try {
    New-Item -Path "D:\Gdump" -Name "$rgflder" -ItemType "directory" -ErrorAction Stop
    }
catch [System.IO.IOException] 
    {
    "Exception caught!"
    }
```

Alternatively, you can manage this within your session by setting `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`, which will apply to all commands within that session.

Keep in mind that the value passed to `-ErrorAction` overrides the setting in `$ErrorActionPreference`. Also, error action settings have no affect on terminating errors. So you cannot expect to set `-ErrorAction Continue` and have code continue processing on a terminating error.

Many commands return objects that may or may not be terminating errors. You will find more success explicitly, specifying when you want to throw a terminating error.

You can read more about error action preference at [About Common Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-6). I actually like [Everything About Exceptions](https://powershellexplained.com/2017-04-10-Powershell-exceptions-everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know/) for exception handling in PowerShell.

Comment: Hi  @AdminOfThings thanks for the quick reply , I tried using the -ErrorAction Stop , but still the script is stopping execution because of DirectoryExists.Exception .

Comment: If you don't want to the code to stop, then you shouldn't use try-catch. You should just omit `-erroraction`. Run `$error.clear()` before the `New-Item` command and look at `$error[0]` to see if it exists.

Comment: Hi @AdminOfThings thanks for the reply,I have removed the try-catch block as you mentioned and put $error.clear() , still i see the error Directory Exist,Microsoft.Powershell.Command

Comment: If you don't want to see the output, then you just need to set your `New-Item` command to `$null` like `$null = New-Item .... `

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply do like below?

```
$rgflder="ilalog"

# combine the path and foldername
$rgPath = Join-Path -Path 'D:\Gdump' -ChildPath $rgflder

# test if the folder already exists
if (Test-Path $rgPath -PathType Container) {
    Write-Output "Directory Exists"
}
else {
    # if not, create the new folder
    try {
        $null = New-Item -Path $rgPath -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Output "Created directory '$rgPath'"
    }
    catch {
        # something terrible happened..
        Write-Error "Error creating folder '$rgPath': $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}
```